# Irregularities with array_intersect & array_unique

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem concerning occurrences of irregularities in correlation with the utilization of array_intersect as well as array_unique.

Please bear in mind that it's an old environement and mysqli can't be used.

There are four MySQL queries in the first step of my script.
They feature the same following structure:

```
$aid_1 = mysql_query("SELECT aid FROM xy WHERE (bid = '20' OR bid = '34') AND baseData BETWEEN $select_1 AND $select_2");
```

`$select_1` et cetera derive from HTML select lists (eight total, two at a time as "from" and "to" for one scope).
This procedure works fine, I checked the results as follows:

```
while($row_aid_1 = mysql_fetch_array(aid_1))
{
    echo '</br> — ' . $row_aid_1['aid'] . '</br>';
}
```

It's the second step where the irregularities occur.
I would like to get the values which are to be found in the results of all four queries of the first step.
I realized this as follows:

```
while(($row_aid_1 = mysql_fetch_array($aid_1)) && ($row_aid_2 = mysql_fetch_array($aid_2)) && ($row_aid_3 = mysql_fetch_array($aid_3)) && ($row_aid_4 = mysql_fetch_array($aid_4)))
{
    $aid_array = array($row_aid_1, $row_aid_2, $row_aid_3, $row_aid_4);
    $aid_ai = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $aid_array);
    $aid_u = array_unique($aid_ai);

    print_r('</br> — ' . $aid_u[0] . '</br>');

    var_dump($aid_u);
}
```

Again, `print_r` and `var_dump` are used to check the results.
Concerning `array_intersect` these are alright as long as the lowest or rather highest values from the select lists mentioned above are used.
Provided that ohter values than the lowest / highest are used, the function works only sometimes.
The times it doesn't, the logs show either "PHP Notice: Undefined index" or "PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0" for the antepenultimate line (`print_r('</br> — ' . $aid_u[0] . '</br>');`).
I can't contrive what the error is exactly since it occurs, as mentioned, only sometimes.
It's obvious though that the error has to be somewhere in the second step since the first one works in all cases (cross-checked as named above) and index / offset are defined in the first step.

I tried a intermediate step with array_values before array_unique, but this doesn't change anything.

The `array_unique` doesn't work at all.
The results are printed almost always twice.

I would really appreciate it if someone could understand as well as explain why the index or rather offset is sometimes undefined and why array_unique doesn't work.

Comment: There's no need for `call_user_func_array`, just do `array_intersect($row_aid_1, $row_aid_2, $row_aid_3, $row_aid_4)`

Comment: Seems to me like this could all just be turned into one query where you just include in the select list whether `baseData between $select_1 AND $select_2`. `SELECT aid, IF(baseData BETWEEN $select1 AND $select2, 1, 0) AS select12, ...[same for 34, 45...etc]...`

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: @Brian If the server is that old, it's probably full of unpatched security holes, so I hope this is nowhere near the public internet.

Answer (score 1):

You're just intersecting each row, not intersecting all the results as a group. This will only work if all the queries return the same results in the same order.

Instead, for each query make an array of all its results, then intersect them all.

```
$aid1_results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($aid_1)) {
    $aid1_results[] = $row['aid'];
}
$aid2_results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($aid_2)) {
    $aid2_results[] = $row['aid'];
}
...
$aid_ai = array_intersect($aid1_results, $aid2_results, $aid3_results, $aid4_results);
```

You can also do it with a `JOIN` in SQL:

```
SELECT t1.aid
FROM (SELECT aid FROM ... WHERE ...) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT aid FROM ... WHERE ...) AS t2 ON t1.aid = t2.aid
JOIN (SELECT aid FROM ... WHERE ...) AS t3 ON t1.aid = t3.aid
JOIN (SELECT aid FROM ... WHERE ...) AS t4 ON t1.aid = t4.aid
```

Comment: Thank your for your examples. :) The array_unique was only used because some values appeared twice. Primarily, I need the aid's which are to be found once in each of the four queries, not only in 1, 2 or 3 of the queries. I don't see how the array_intersect would work with your code since it needs at least two parameters. Therefore I used the line while(($row_aid_1 = mysql_fetch_array($aid_1)) && ($row_aid_2 = ... So, what do you mean with "You need to get the results of all the queries into an array[...]"?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were doing, I've revised the answer.

Comment: To test against a list you use `AND aid IN (1, 2, 3)` not `AND aid = (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Isn't `WHERE bid = '20'` in the original queries? Why do you need to use the received aid's in another query that does that?

Comment: OK, so use `WHERE aid IN (received aid's)`

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong from that snippet. Ask a new question and show the whole code.